# How to make my application DPI-aware?

Tags: c++, scaling, dpi, dpi-aware

When a user sets the DPI scaling to draw fonts and windows larger in all displays, I don't want my application to be affected (I don't want my application's fonts and controls get larger)

I tried to use [SetProcessDPIAware() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or add a manifest file, but it didn't work. How can I prevent windows (XP, 7 and 8) to change my application's font size?

Comment: Current medium-high resolution screens are already causing users to complain "Text is miniscule! Menus are unreadable!" for [badly written interfaces](http://forums.adobe.com/message/6183761). Imagine >300dpi screens, 'coming soon'. It begs the question, **why** would you want this?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the wrong question. You want it to be DPI-independent. The answer is to size everything in points, and everything relative to that in ems. Avoid DPI and pixels completely.

Comment: What can I do about font size?